# 2 rewrite rules not working together

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a rewrite rule for my product detail page so that instead of the url being

`/product-detail.php?id=3765`

it is instead:

```
/blue-jeans
```

This is the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ product-detail.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
```

However, I need another one for my regional dealers. As soon as I add this to my .htaccess, the product detail rule stops working in that a blank page is displayed when navigating to a product. How can I get them both to work?

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ dealers.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Well, that does not really make sense and is impossible to achieve. Simply because you currently use the same, identical pattern for both rules. How do you expect something different to happen if you use the same pattern How should the system know the difference? By magic? Or intuition? You need to able to explain and implement a difference between the two cases. If you can't, then the system certainly can't.

Comment: I thought they would be different because the url is different i.e.: dealers.php vs product-detail.php

Comment: Sure, the _target_ may be different. But think from the rewriting engine's point of view for a second. It receives a request to for example `/green`. How is it meant to decide if "green" is a dealer or a product? So to which target to rewrite to? You see: it needs some way to tell both cases apart. Any details may be used, but you have to name _some_ detail.

Comment: Ah, I see. Ahmed has mentioned that below. I just can't get it to work though by simply adding /dealers/ or /products/ in front of the regex. I get a 'not found' error.

Comment: You cannot only change the pattern. You have to change the URLs such that they can be told apart with different regexes. Or you can name a rule by which separate number circles (pools) for the IDs can be told apart. I have the impression you have not yet really understood how rewriting actually works. You appear to expect something from it that cannot be fulfilled: to know your thoughts.

Comment: Your impression is correct. I am a beginner at rule rewriting hence me asking the question on this platform.

Comment: Sure, all fine. We all started once and we all still learn. You need to understand that rewriting is simple string handling in the end. It sees the string standing for an incoming request and tries to match pattern against it. First match, first serve. That's all. So the question you have to answer first is: how do the strings differ that should be rewritten to either dealers or products. As said before: if you can't, then the engine can't. If the same number circle is used (I doubt that...), then ther is no way to tell them apart. So: how do _you_ tell them apart?

Comment: Hmm. I actually seem to have gotten it to work. I changed Ahmed's example from /dealers/ to just dealers/ and it now works!

Comment: Without changing the URLs of the incoming requests? I doubt that, actually. But whatever, if you are happy all is fine ;-)

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I changed my navigation url to example.com/dealers/my-dealer-region and it does work. And the products still work too.

Comment: Ah, so you _did_ change the URLs. That way you took care the there now _is_ something by which the engine can tell the two situations apart, since you can not use _different_ patterns and only one will match for each request. Exactly what I suggested above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because the matching regex are identical, and the first one of them matches and so you're done.  You need a wrapping php script that can sort this out for you or have some other token in your regex to limit the scope. For example you could say that all products are under /products and all dealers are under /dealers, and then do something like:

```
  RewriteRule ^/dealers/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ /dealers.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^/products/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ /products.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, Ahmed. Adding /dealers/ or /products/ gives me a 'not found' error. e.g.: example.com/products/blue-jeans

Comment: woops I meant to say /products.php?slug=$1 [NC,L] I'll fix